# How to remove anything before and after google sheets SPLITs using the SPLIT funtion

Tags: google-sheets

I have a working SPLIT function. The challenge is that I have excesses that I would like to remove. So basically, I have a paragraph of some sort with a delimiter which I am using to pick parts of the phrase. I am able to use the SPLIT function to extract what I need but I have too many columns which become useless after the SPLIT.

**My Original Phrase:**

**Lorem Ipsum** is ***title*** simply dummy ***style*** text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever ***title*** since the 1500s ***style*** when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic ***title*** typesetting, remaining ***style*** essentially unchanged.

I use the following formula to add a single delimiter

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"title","❤️"),"style","❤️")
```

**Phrase with delimiter**

**Lorem Ipsum** is ❤️simply dummy❤️ text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever ❤️since the 1500s❤️ when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic ❤️typesetting, remaining ❤️essentially unchanged.

This is the formula I'm using to split.

```
=SPLIT(B1,"❤️",0)
```

So after doing this, I have what I need in separate columns but is there a way to remove the rest of the phrase totally so that the formula below just displays the required columns only?

Link to the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/154Njb_tM43dWnP3iwt09na6bY_zInTDx799FQoQGefQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in B1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"title","❤️♦"),"style","❤️")
```

use in C1:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(B1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(B1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", ))
```